# Drafting Double-Faced Cards and Basic Lands

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I’ve just played my very first draft at my LGS and was surprised about the following two “rules”:

1. We got to announce our double-faced cards right after opening each of the boosters. As far as I remember, according to official rules players can announce their DFC but they are not required to do so.
2. We passed our basic lands (both foil and non-foil ones) around the table, with only tokens and AD cards being removed from boosters. I wonder if there is an official rule regarding this moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Magic: The Gathering Tournament Rules (found at https://WPN.Wizards.com/en/resources/rules-documents), section 7.7 "Booster Draft Procedures":

> Players open their first booster
> pack and count the cards face down, removing token cards, rules cards, and any other non-game cards.

> Players are not permitted to reveal hidden information of any kind to other participants in the draft regarding their own picks or what they want others to pick. (Exception: This does not apply to double-faced cards, both faces of which may be revealed at any time during a draft.)